# 24-bit samples with "odd" data length

Tags: python

I am using `python` and `scipy.io.wavfile` to read 24-bit wav files. I know `wavfile` has issues about 24-bit and I manually integrated the solution suggested by Warren in the issue. In practice the update in the code consists in grouping the bytes 3-by-3 and compute 24-bit integers (code below adapted from Warren Weckesser):

```
if bit_depth not in (8, 16, 32, 64, 96, 128):
    # first read byte per byte

    data = numpy.fromfile(fid, dtype='u1')
    for i in range(len(data) % 3):
        data = numpy.delete(data, len(data) - 1)
        # or data = numpy.delete(data, 0)?
    a = numpy.empty((int(len(data)/3), 4), dtype='u1')
    #print(data.shape)
    a[:, :3] = data.reshape((-1, 3))
    a[:, 3:] = (a[:, 3 - 1:3] >> 7) * 255
    data = a.view('<i4').reshape(a.shape[:-1])
```

Some wav samples report a 24-bit depth, but the actual data is not multiple of 3 (eg, 2138890 bytes). This puzzles me: are there metadata that wavfile is not skipping? Should I remove some bytes from the array? From the start of it or from the end? Did someone stumble in the same problem?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What was the codec used to record the file? (When you say the length of the actual data is not a multiple of 3, does this considers the metadata and other information of the file or just the bytes that make up the sound?)

Comment: I don't know the used codec, these are third party files, most of which are correctly read without the lines `for i in range ... delete()` that I added to address the problem. The data being read is processed by `scipy.io.wavfile`, so if there was metadata in it it would mean `wavfile` is written much worse than I expected...

Comment: Thank you. Please see [this link](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Interchange_File_Format). What I am trying to say is that you may be looking at the raw encoded data, not the data of the recording. Where are these recordings coming from, if I may ask? Are they too long? Can you decode some but not others?

Comment: Thank YOU :) I guess this is the only explanation. Yes, I can decode say 98% of them, they come from a professional sample library and "should" be all equal in terms of metadata. It seems the actual solution by WarrenWeckesser already addresses this issue.

Comment: No worries, glad it was helpful.